# What is this oil? (wet lube)

Tags: shimano, chain, lubricant

I needed wet lube for my chain, so I went to my local cycle store and bought the following pictured Shimano wet lube.

Back home, out of curiosity, I "googled" it, and surprisingly enough, I didn't found any picture of it on the Web. Now I'm really wondering, do you guys have any idea of the origin of this product?

The label is in Dutch, French and Danish. The company is noted as "Shimano Workshop > Shimano Europe", headquartered in the Netherlands. The only reference number is WS000002-A.

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Comment: Old packaging maybe, the Shimano lube products are generally in a rectangular bottle now. Possibly old stock the retailer was selling off? Who knows apart from Shimano themselves, give them a shout and ask.

Comment: I thought of old packaging… that would be a very old one! Indeed, for such questions the best is usually to contact the manufacter directly.

Comment: If the packaging is old enough to pre-date URLs and even barcodes then it may be very old indeed.   Or it may be a bulk-bottle sold to bike shops for internal use, a "not for resale" bottle somewhat like individual cans of soft-drink in a 12 pack.

Comment: Ah ah, not *that* old, there's a barcode and even an URL! I also thought of a "not for sale" product. The shop had added on top their own barcode sticker (the white thing on 2nd picture), sadly, trying to remove it, I damaged the original label and couldn't read what was written on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably have Shimano's wet lube.  Confidence could increase if you feel that the point of sale was a reputable store with legitimate distributorship.   Speaking of all that, are you a believer that Amazon represents a company like that?   [Here's an Amazon post](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00389IKXY) in which the label appears very similar and the manufacturers reference number begins "WS..."

While this rationale is fairly weak counterfeiting a relatively inexpensive product isn't cost effective, legalities aside.  As they say, "the proof is in the pudding," so I would try it out and see how it works out.

Comment: Yes, the store is a reputable one. I remember I had bought them some tools (crank extractor, bottom bracket remover), and it also was brands unfoundable on the web! Like Chinese brands, but upper-range quality (good material, good manufacturing). I really don't know how they do… It's like they are hand-picking each of the models they are offering for sale. So, the product should be ok, though I prefer to make sure.

Comment: Just a comment on the big river post: one review says 
"It seems like the bike, firearm, and other industries are rife with "specialty" oils. For years I've had great luck using plain old Mobil 1 automotive oil on nearly everything mechanical, but it made a mess on a bike chain." Who would know that different (*specialty*) oils have different usage :D !